# How can I check the user input multiple character inside my char?

Tags: c, char

```
do{
    char reply;

    printf("Enter your choice > ")
    scanf("%c", &reply)

    if (isdigit(reply) != 0){
        //inside are my contents not really important       
        //what I want to ask is, if user input 123, because it is a char, hence 1 will be taken but it is a wrong input. How can i check it and print a "invalid input"?
    
    }

}while (reply != 3)
```

Comment: you can ask `scanf()` to read more than 1 char, with %s. That would allow you to check the length of the read string, then if correct, use isdigit() for the 1st char.

Comment: What he said, but don't forget to watch out for buffer overflows, since `%s` will read as many characters as are written, and can easily overflow your char buffer. Prefer `fgets` than `scanf()`

Comment: @Angevil ahh Thank you so much, I solved it just now. Thank you!

Comment: @Adalcar I see... Thank you too

Comment: Remember too that [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer).